# How can I trigger this change function if either of 2 elements change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

How can I trigger this function if either ".ranking" or ".complaint select" are changed?

This change function adds and/or remove values from "increase_priority1" when the user selects a complaint and ranks the importance level of the issue. At the moment it's only being triggered when "ranking" changes, and therefore if the user changes the issue but not the importance level it isn't changing the value accordingly.

```
var $increase_priority1 = $(".increase_priority1");
// If value is "Shoulders", complaint was Shoulders too small (select name=Shoulders value=Too_small) and it was assigned a level 1 priority (select class="ranking shoulders" value=1). 
// var's for other issues and priority levels go here

$(".ranking, .complaint select").change(function () {
   var name = $(this).data("name"); //get priority name    

   if ($(".complaint select").val() === "Too_small" && $(this).val() == 1 && !$(this).data("increase_priority1")) {
       //rank is 1, and not yet added to priority list
       $("<option>", {
           text: name,
           val: name
       }).appendTo($increase_priority1);
       $(this).data("increase_priority1", true); //flag as a priority item
   }
   if ($(this).data("increase_priority1") && ($(this).val() != 1 || $(".complaint select").val() != "Too_small")) {
       //is in priority list, but now demoted
       $("option[value=" + name + "]", $increase_priority1).remove();
       $(this).removeData("increase_priority1"); //no longer a priority item
   }
   // Similar If Statements to set & unset other elements go here
});
```

There are several complaint and ranking elements, reflecting the various areas customers complain about and ranking on a scale of 1 - 5.

Fiddle which shows this in context: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/vWLEn/168/

Comment: Consider using a [beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: Careful with `$(this).val() == 1`. It works because of `==` which doesn't care about type but `val()` returns a string.

Comment: try using "onchange" for $(".increase_rank1").onchange(function () {});

Comment: @GiantHornet  you need to read the Jquery API...there is no such method.

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks for pointing that out :-) I tried replacing .val() with .value but that doesn't work. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: Your function *is* being triggered when either the `.ranking` or `.complaint select` elements are being changed. You can prove it by adding this code at the beginning of the function: `alert($(this).attr('name'))` (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWLEn/179/) for an example). I don't think the problem is whether the function is triggering. Rather, there's an issue with the logic in your code.

Comment: @Lorax: Thank you for helping me narrow down the problem. Any suggestions as to what the logic problem is?

Comment: @ChayaCooper, for a start the `$(".complaint select")` in the first `if` statement in the code (above) will target *all* the `span.complaint` elements. You need to narrow down which one fired the event (using `$(this)` to work out which dropdown was changed).

Comment: @Lorax, I've actually been driving myself a little crazy trying to figure out how to use (this) for 2 separate elements in the same statement. Any chance you know how to do that?

Comment: See my answer to the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be easier if you restructured your code. How about this:

**HTML**:

```
<label for="priority1Issues">First Priority</label>
<select id="priority1Issues" class="priorityIssue" multiple></select>

<label for="priority2Issues">Second Priority</label>
<select id="priority2Issues" class="priorityIssue" multiple></select>

<br />
<div class="complaint">
    <label for="shoulders">Shoulders</label>
    <select id="shoulders" class="complaintOpt complaintItem">
        <option value="Null">Select</option>
        <option value="too_big">Too Big</option>
        <option value="too_small">Too Small</option>
    </select>

    <label for="shouldersRanking">Ranking</label>
    <select id="shouldersRanking" class="complaintOpt complaintRanking">
        <option value="Null">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now you can use the `<div>` with class `complaint` to selectively target it's content:

**JavaScript**:

```
$('.complaint select.complaintOpt').change(function() {
    var $container = $(this).parent(),
        $item = $container.find('.complaintItem'),
        itemId = $item.attr('id'),
        itemVal = $item.val(),
        itemText = $item.find('option[value=' + itemVal + ']').html(),
        rank = $container.find('.complaintRanking').val();

    // Ignore if not a complete complaint
    if((itemVal == 'Null') || (rank == 'Null')) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove any existing complaint (using the CSS class to target the correct option)
    $('select.priorityIssue option.' + itemId).remove();

    // Add new complaint (we include a CSS class to make it easier to refer to this
    //   particular type of complaint later, if necessary)
    $('#priority' + rank + 'Issues')
        .append($('<option>' + itemText + '</option>').addClass(itemId));
});
```

You should now be able to duplicate the 'complaint div' for other items (just make sure you change the IDs of the `<select>` elements in the new `div`). There is an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6YnQd/

Comment: That worked :-D There are two things that I'd need to modify but couldn't figure out how to do. 1) How would I specify the item's name instead of itemText (since many of items have the same option values)? 2) In most instances I need to separate the answers for priority1Issues, priority2Issues, etc. into categories indicating the overall goal (i.e. Increase vs. Decrease), but it didn't work with ($(".complaintItem").val() === "Too_small"). I added the names and new elements to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/6YnQd/31/

Comment: @ChayaCooper: (1) Just use `$item.attr('name')` to get the value of the `name` attribute. (2) When it comes to identifying what categories things fall into, CSS classes are your friend. Just add (for example) `goal-increase` and `goal-decrease` classes to your `option` elements and then extract them from the item to find out which box to display them in. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6YnQd/33/

Comment: OMG! goal-increase and goal-decrease were the perfect solution (and I learned something new too :-D). I'm having a bit of difficulty with $item.attr('name') though. I tried replacing itemText with that, as well as mimicking the 2 steps used for itemText without any luck. Would you mind showing me where to insert it?

Comment: @ChayaCooper, you'll need to add a `name="..."` attribute to the `<select>` elements inside the `.complaint` divs for it to work (e.g. `<select id="shoulders" name="Shoulders">`). I just noticed that you added the names to the `<label>` element, but that's not the right place to put them.

Comment: Oops! Not sure how that happened :-( I'm glad you caught that ;-) And thank you so much for helping me figure this out :-D

Comment: I discovered that it wasn't removing items if complaintRanking was unselected, but switching around the remove and if statements seems to fix that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
$(".ranking, .complaint select").change(function() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Zoltan_Toth: I think that's on the right track but since the function isn't getting triggered when .complaint select changes it may need something in addition to that. I've updated the question to include this (as well as reflect ways I've simplified the code) :-)